# MenuItem needs to be clicked 2 times to get activated

Tags: android, menuitem

i am building an application in which i have to display a `PopupMenu` from a `MenuItem` in the `Toolbar`. The problem is that i have to click 2 times in the `MenuItem` so that i can see the `PopupMenu`.

My code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.lobby_activity_menu, menu);


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mFilterMenuItem = findViewById(R.id.action_search_filter_menu_item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search_menu_item: {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Search button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.action_search_filter_menu_item:{

                mFilterMenuItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        TileMenu tileMenu = new TileMenu(GuestActivity.this, v, R.menu.filter_menu);
                        Log.e("MENU ITEM", mFilterMenuItem.toString());
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
            default: {
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

How to fix it to be activated with 1 click?

Comment: You don't need a `OnClickListener` on your menu item - the clicked item is the `MenuItem` provided in the method argument `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

Comment: thank you mate you save the day!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need not set a onClickListener again on your menu item :

```
case R.id.action_search_filter_menu_item:
              TileMenu tileMenu = new TileMenu(GuestActivity.this, R.menu.filter_menu);

            return true;
```

Comment: it expects a View to be anchored to

Comment: you  can pass the  mFilterMenuItem object, which you create in the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

@Tasd try replacing your block of code with this

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mFilterMenuItem = findViewById(R.id.action_search_filter_menu_item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search_menu_item: {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Search button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.action_search_filter_menu_item:{

                Toast.makeText(this, "Search filter button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            default: {
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where did you get the v?

Comment: Try with this. check the occurence of toast messagess and it should work with the first click itself